# PrintWindow and Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, microsoft-edge

we have a problem with the PrintWindow function on Windows 10 (build 10166). When we call PrintWindow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx) to capture a image of the Microsoft Edge (Project Spartan) browser window we get a black image.

Does anyone know the reason of this and how could it be fixed/avoided? Or maybe some other way to capture image of a window, that can be in background and hided behind another windows?

**UPDATE**: We've tried sending WM_PRINTCLIENT and WM_PRINT messages, and calling DefWindowProc with WM_PRINT, but results are the same - just a black image. We also tried to use BitBlt to copy window's DC to a memory surface, but it's not working too. Best solution that we have now is bringing browser window to foreground, capturing the entire screen and cropping screenshot to window's client size; but it can interrupt and annoy users because of switching application that's currently in use.

Comment: Quite likely this is simply impossible

Comment: Here some other cases when PrintWindow doesn't work https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/d9a188ae-3503-4c31-aa00-6e7195b5384a/printwindow-bugs

Comment: `WM_PRINTCLIENT` has to be supported by the window in question (despite rumours to the contrary, Windows does not step in and do a `WM_PAINT` to a memory bitmap as a last resort)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thanks for you comment, I've tried sending WM_PRINTCLIENT and WM_PRINT messages, and calling DefWindowProc with WM_PRINT, but results are same - just a black image.

Comment: @Andrey That's not what Jonathan meant you can't call DefWindowProc unless you've injected code into the process. And you can't synthesise WM_PAINT messages. As I said, it might not be possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a screenshot of the page on the browser. try this JavaScript library: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ 
The script traverses through the DOM of the page it is loaded on. It gathers information on all the elements there, which it then uses to build a representation of the page. In other words, it does not actually take a screenshot of the page, but builds a representation of it based on the properties it reads from the DOM.

I just tried on my machine on Microsoft Edge and Chrome and worked on both.Hope that does the job!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IE
[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786093/5148765).
The most stable result was with double call

```
PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, 0);
PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, PW_CLIENTONLY);
```