# How capture only Microsoft Edge browser window?

Tags: delphi, canvas, microsoft-edge

I need capture **Microsoft Edge** window and have tried with [`PrintWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but **[unfortunately it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405274/printwindow-and-microsoft-edge)**. Then, now i want try using `Canvas.CopyRect` api.

I have tried with following code but is causing a *Access violation* error on line showed in screenshot below:

```
procedure ScreenShotWindow;
var
  c: TCanvas;
  r, t: TRect;
  h: THandle;
  Bild: TBitMap;
begin
  c := TCanvas.Create;
  h := FindWindow(nil, 'Microsoft Edge');
  c.Handle := GetWindowDC(h);
  GetWindowRect(h, t);
  try
    r := Rect(0, 0, t.Right - t.Left, t.Bottom - t.Top);
    Bild.Width  := t.Right - t.Left; { <-- Access Violation Here }
    Bild.Height := t.Bottom - t.Top;
    Bild.Canvas.CopyRect(r, c, t);
    Bild.SaveToFile('test'+ RandomPassword(10)+'.bmp');
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, c.Handle);
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I still not know if after fix this code, this will be able to capture **Microsoft Edg**, so if someone know some way that works, also say me please :D.

Comment: Next time please indicate the line of access violation or other error with a comment (// access violation on this line) in your code instead of an image of your code.

Comment: Indeed, images take up space that somebody else pays for :-) So if it's not absolutely necessary, people should refrain from uploading pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created `Bild` yet in your code. This needs to be created first before you can use it (and destroyed once you're done with it).

```
procedure ScreenShotWindow;
var
  c: TCanvas;
  r, t: TRect;
  h: THandle;
  Bild: TBitMap;
begin
  c := TCanvas.Create;
  h := FindWindow(nil, 'Microsoft Edge');
  c.Handle := GetWindowDC(h);
  GetWindowRect(h, t);
  try
    r := Rect(0, 0, t.Right - t.Left, t.Bottom - t.Top);
    Bild := TBitMap.Create;
    try
      Bild.Width  := t.Right - t.Left;
      Bild.Height := t.Bottom - t.Top;
      Bild.Canvas.CopyRect(r, c, t);
      Bild.SaveToFile('test'+ RandomPassword(10)+'.bmp');
    finally
      Bild.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, c.Handle);
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you. Now, why i get only a piece of window? [Eg: notepad.exe](http://image.prntscr.com/image/b7fffb4f0fa54fd1a3f20418d2f6b9cf.png)

Comment: @Franciscocamilo Not sure, you'll have to ask another question about that.